# How to use private class variable using interface implemented in a different class

Tags: java, oop

Food is a standalone class, doesn't inherits from anything.

```
public class Food {
    private String name;

    public Food() {}
                
    public Food(String Name) {
        this.name = Name;
    }
                
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
                
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } }
```

Below is the interface:

> ```
> public interface Eater{
>   public void eat(Food food);
> }
> ```

How can i use the interface in **Person** class (see below) to access private variable **name** from **Food** class?

Here is what I am trying to do by **creating an object explicitly**:

```
public class Person implements Eater {
    public String foodName;
        
    public void eat(Food food) {
        Food testFood = new Food();
        this.foodName = testFood.getName();
    }
}
```

But how can i do something like that **without creating an object explicitly**? Because I want this method to work for every instanced of **Food**.

Comment: I do not get the point. An instance of `Food food` is passed as parameter to the method. Why don't you use that parameter?

Comment: Why are you creating `testFood` if you're receiving in input `food`? It shouldn't even be possible btw (there is no empty constructor in the class `Food`)

Comment: `food.getName()` ? Also I think you want to let class `Person` to implement `inteface Eater`

Comment: @Turing85 like food.getName(); ? Can you explain more?

Comment: @PritomSarker `this.foodName = food.getName();`

Comment: @hev1 This answers my question completely. I have definitely tried that but I must have omitted something else somewhere and couldn't make it work. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PritomSarker No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `getName` on the `food` parameter.

```
public class Person implements Eater {
    public String foodName;
        
    public void eat(Food food) {
        this.foodName = food.getName();
    }
}
```